# how to reenter text in text view at end of previous text in ios sdk?

Tags: ios, ios5

I want to enter text in textview at the end of previous text for that i want when i click on textview at any position the cursor position should be end of the previous text in text view.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Holex,i tried NSUInteger length = self.textView.text.length;  
    self.textView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(length, 0);
    [textView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, length) animated:YES]; in textViewShouldBeginEditing,textViewDidBeginEditing,shouldChangeTextInRange delegate method but it will not fulfill my requirement..

Comment: actually what i want...if my text view height is 20 and i m writing on it if may text is more than textview height then it will automatically scroll now i want to enter text in textview  after few time then when i clicked any where in textview at that time cursor location should be end of last line what ever i wrote earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  NSUInteger length = self.textView.text.length;  
    self.textView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(length, 0);
    [textView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, length) animated:YES];
```

use it in beginEditing.

Comment: Thanx for u r reply, i already use this but it is not full fill may requirement... actually what i want...if my text view height is 20 and i m writing on it if may text is more than textview height then it will automatically scroll now i want to enter text in textview  after few time then when i clicked any where in textview at that time cursor location should be end of last line what ever i wrote earlier.